# Where can I find comatose-rubyisbeautiful tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

Now I am trying to convert Rails2 application into Rails3 one.
And I used comatose as CMS in old project, but now I can not find Rails3 compatible comatose version.

Instead, I did find comatose-rubyisbeautiful gem.
So I added it in my Gemfile, and installed.
And executed the command "rails generate comatose".
It generated initializers/comatose.rb and new migration file.
Then the next step is to execute migration, by "rake db:migrate".

But it shoots me an error, like the following.
    "Uninitialized constant Comatose" in config/initializers/comatose.rb

Is there anything wrong?
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the fork.  I haven't touched it in years.  I hope you have found an alternative since September.  If not, I can help get you going with what is there, but I am not sure that I will actively maintain the gem.  There has not been much interest other than the one company for whom I brought the old Comatose up to date.